# How to create a MySql user-defined function in a WordPress plugin installation?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, installation, user-defined-functions

I have written a script that creates a user-defined function (UDF) for the MySql database.

I need this UDF for a plugin that I am writing in WordPress.

Is there any way to add this UDF to the database from within the regular WordPress plugin installation scripts? (such as the "dbDelta" function for installing database tables).

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to add this UDF to the database from within the regular WordPress plugin installation scripts? (such as the "dbDelta" function for installing database tables).

[Judging from the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins), the `dbDelta` function takes arbitrary SQL.  As long as whatever underlying mechanism that is being used allows UDFs to be created, then you should not have an issue simply creating it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. After thinking a bit about this issue, I found the solution: 1. Use $wpdb->query('place the create function code here'); 2. Don't use the delimiter command in your sql command (such as 'delimiter //') - just use the default semi-colon (';') delimiter.