# Create MySQL function by wordpress plugin

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I would like to create a MySQL function in the user's database when they install my Wordpress plugin.

I've tried this code:

```
$wpdb->query(
"
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION `myfunc`(t TEXT CHARSET utf8) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'ą', 'a');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'Ą', 'A');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'ć', 'c');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'Ć', 'C');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'ę', 'e');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'Ę', 'E');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'ł', 'l');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'Ł', 'L');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'ń', 'n');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'Ń', 'N');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'ó', 'o');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'Ó', 'O');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'ś', 's');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'Ś', 'S');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'ż', 'z');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'Ż', 'Z');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'ź', 'z');
        SET t = REPLACE(t, 'Ź', 'Z');
        return t;
    END
"
);
```

but it doesn't work, the function is not created. Is there any other way to insert this function from a Wordpress plugin?

Comment: Does any query get run by this command? Does this query process properly if you enter it into MySQL directly? Have you checked if the database user has `CREATE_ROUTINE` privileges?

Comment: yes, if i login to phpmyadmin and run it query(as same user) it works perfectly

Comment: Ok, what is the context of this code? What file is it in, how is it being called? Please edit your answer to include more of the code. Also ensure you're logging or displaying errors, and provide them here.

Comment: Also have you tried removing the `DELIMITER` statement? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364590/how-to-create-a-mysql-user-defined-function-in-a-wordpress-plugin-installation) had similar problems, but went unanswered. The `DELIMITER` statement is used on the command line but shouldn't be necessary when sending things from PHP.

Answer (score 3):

`CREATE FUNCTION` is not supported by dbDelta function. It only supports the following SQL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE
CREATE DATABASE
INSERT INTO
UPDATE
```

Here is code snippet from dbDelta function

> https://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php

```
foreach ( $queries as $qry ) {
    if ( preg_match( '|CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*)|', $qry, $matches ) ) {
        $cqueries[ trim( $matches[1], '`' ) ] = $qry;
        $for_update[ $matches[1] ]            = 'Created table ' . $matches[1];
    } elseif ( preg_match( '|CREATE DATABASE ([^ ]*)|', $qry, $matches ) ) {
        array_unshift( $cqueries, $qry );
    } elseif ( preg_match( '|INSERT INTO ([^ ]*)|', $qry, $matches ) ) {
        $iqueries[] = $qry;
    } elseif ( preg_match( '|UPDATE ([^ ]*)|', $qry, $matches ) ) {
        $iqueries[] = $qry;
    } else {
        // Unrecognized query type.
    }
}
```